# Xcode 4.5 & iOS 6 Linking error with Tapuku Library

Tags: ios, xcode, three20, ios6, xcode4.5

I only receive this error when my project compiles for running on an iOS device.  Has anyone experienced an issue similar to this?  I am attempting to run my project on a device.  I have looked just about everywhere and am unable to find a solution.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
Ld /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/McKendree.app/McKendree normal armv7
    cd /Users/dapage/Developer/workspace/McKendree
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/dapage/Developer/workspace/McKendree -L/Users/dapage/Developer/workspace/McKendree/Libraries -L/Users/dapage/Developer/workspace/McKendree/Libraries/OAuthConsumer -L/Users/dapage/Developer/workspace/McKendree/Libraries/TestFlight -L/Users/dapage/Developer/workspace/McKendree/../../../Downloads/TestFlightSDK1 -F/Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist "/Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Intermediates/McKendree University.build/Debug-iphoneos/McKendree.build/Objects-normal/armv7/McKendree.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -ObjC -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UI.a /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UICommon.a /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UINavigator.a /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libextThree20XML.a /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20.a /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Core.a /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Network.a /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Style.a /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libTapkuLibrary.a -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -lz -framework QuartzCore -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework MapKit -framework MessageUI -framework MediaPlayer -framework AVFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreLocation -lxml2 -lsqlite3.0 -framework CFNetwork -framework Security -lOAuth -lTestFlight -o /Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/McKendree.app/McKendree\
```

The error is:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/dapage/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/McKendree_University-clkfusicbtxoumeeuoisuduipobw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libTapkuLibrary.a'
```

Comment: It appears the linker cannot find the binary for the library in question at the location specified by whatever you have for the target Library Search Paths.  Is the library located at the path that the error expresses?

Comment: I'm stuck at same point, anyone there for any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the library binary is under the project root and that you add it as a reference. You can do this by selecting the project in the Project Navigator (Cmd-1) and then select Build Phases. Under Link Binary with Libraries you should have a reference to the binary. You may also want to add the library binary to your project, which may automatically at it as a linked binary. You can also edit Library Search Paths under Build Settings and add the folder where you have this binary file.

```
"$(SRCROOT)/lib"
```

If you have the binary in that folder it may find it easier that way. You will also need to reference headers for this library so look at setting Header Search Paths and adding the header files to your project.

If you can, I prefer to add code from third party libraries as Static Libraries and adding them as a dependency. You can do this first as a separate project and get it to build successfully on it's own. Then you can drag that project file into the other project in Xcode and set it up as a dependency. You will need to understand how schemes manage the build project for dependencies to set up a sub-project. You may find this approach to be much easier than linking to a pre-compiled library which may not include the required architectures for the devices that Apple releases. If you have the source code as a dependencies you will be able to build the necessary binary versions.